# Looping code error-Excel says that it can't find the file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will refresh all workbooks starting with 'FY' in a folder. With the current code, the first two workbooks refresh, but when it comes to the third workbook, I get this error:

> Sorry, we couldn't find FY20 11-15.xlsm\FY20 1-5.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

The path to the workbook is "C:\Documents\Database\Sales".

Here's the code:

```vb
Sub refreshdata()
    Dim file As String
    Dim book As String

    file = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    book = Dir(file & "\FY*.xlsm")

    Do While file <> ""
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file & "\" & book)

        Call Refresh
        wb.Close savechanges:=True
        file = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is because at first your variable `file` was a folder path and then it became a file name. Use two different variables - for example, `sPath` and `sFilename`

Comment: Just replace `Do While file <> ""` with `Do While book <> ""` and `file = Dir` with `book = Dir`

Comment: Would it not just .open(book) as` book` is already the full string variable.

Comment: @Davesexcel no, `Dir(…)` only returns the file name. `book = Dir(file & "\FY*.xlsm")` finds the first file name that matches `FY*.xlsm` in the path `file` and returns the filename only.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes, `file & "\" & book` is just duplicating the directory, that is the point I was making.

Comment: @Davesexcel yes but the reason was that he mixed up the variable names at this point here: `file = Dir` where it should have been `book = Dir` and `Do While book <> ""`. See my answer below. I understood you meant `book` contains *"the full string variable"* (including path) but it only contains the filename, no path. Probably just a misunderstanding then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your variables not clearly and `file` contains actually a path `file = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path` therefore you mixed everything up. Get your variable names more meaningful! Make sure your variables are well named after what content they contain or you confuse yourself.

```
Sub refreshdata()
    Dim Path As String
    Path = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

    Dim FileName As String    
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\FY*.xlsm")

    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & FileName)

        Call Refresh
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

#### What was wrong?

Here `file = Dir` you set your `file` variable which actually was the path to filename. And in the next iteration of the loop `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file & "\" & book)` is twice a filename, the new filename in `file` and the old in `book`.